# Show that $F$ is spanned by a vector all whose components are non-negative and add up to $1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $F$ be a subspace of the vector space $R^d$. Suppose that $F$ contains a vector all whose components are positive. Show that $F$ is spanned by its probability vectors. (By a $\textit{probability vector}$ we mean, a vector all whose components are non-negative and add up to $1$.)

Can you please give me hint/ outline of the proof? I have no idea.

Comment: If they're all positive they add up to some positive number. Multiply the vector by the reciprocal of that number to get the probability vector, then go backwards to show that it's in the span. So for example $(1,1)$ would have probability vector $1/2(1,1) =(1/2,1/2)$ because $1 + 1 = 2$.

Comment: Add a suitable multiple of the positive vector to get an all positive vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u$ be a vector in $F$ with positive components.  Given any other vector $v$ in $F$, choose $a>0$ very large so that the vector
$$
w:= v+au
$$
has positive components.  Then clearly $w$ lies in $F$ and
$$
v= w-au.\qquad(*)
$$
This shows that $F$ is generated by its positive vectors and you now have to tweak $(*)$ a bit to get the same result relative to probability vectors.